# How do I create a widget on android to display a graph of online data?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, widget

I have a profile page as a music curator account, where it shows the score for various parameters there. The most relevant one, monthly listeners, is easily inferred (just a simple excel that I've compiled with the values found on the page), but not shown.
Even though I can constantly calculate it (approximately, because the page might not be consistently updated or might have some flawed calculations), I'm still trying to find a way to have that monthly listeners value updated constantly, and seen as a graph over time.
I was wondering if it's best to do it on android, windows or any other way, to simplify for a complete noob like me, any coding process that i might have to do.
I've only had a little experience in Arduino, so even the basics as to what language to use or the code neccesary for this are foreign to me, but I'm quite interested in learning more about it.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question in it's current form is either too broad or unclear, from the title it sounds like you want to create an Android widget, but from the body it sounds like you don't really have a specific end goal in mind as long as you have a way to visualize the data. In order to receive more relevant help, you should decide what you want the end product to be.

Comment: Again, not the most proficient here when it comes to coding. The idea I have feels best as a widget displaying a line graph, on android. The simplest way I can imagine describing the end product would be a display of historical online data on a chart, extracted from numerical values ( discarding the text surrounding it), from the inbox I have in the platform (html). I hope this clarifies

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if this question belongs on stack overflow. It might, but to me it just seems more like you're asking for some tutorial recommendations than fit answers to a technical problem. https://medium.com/android-bits/android-widgets-ad3d166458d3 has some instructions on creating different forms of widgets, just be warned, a widget is a special view of an application that can be drawn in a different application, the application running the system doesn't have to be complex, and can exist purely to populate the data. BTW you'd be interested in the last type of widget in the article.

Comment: Great! I just wanted some orientation  as to how to approach it, so thank you for the kind answer!